# Cannot call functions after creating a python package

Tags: python, pypi, twine

Recently I created my first package called pycohort: https://pypi.org/project/pycohort/

Here there are existing python functions that are working without any issues. A snippet from the code looks like this:

```
# packages needed
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def calculate_mean(some_list):

    """Function to calculate the mean of the data set.
    Returns: 
        float: mean of the data set
    """

    return (1.0 * sum(some_list) / len(some_list))
```

I first `pip install pycohort` and then `import pycohort`. When I call the above mentioned function like `pycohort.calculate_mean(df.col1)`, I get the error message: `AttributeError: module 'pycohort' has no attribute 'calculate_mean'`.

While uploading the function, I navigated to my current working directory and then entered the below code. But I don't suspect that there is an issue here since I was able to upload and pip install successfully.

```
python setup.py sdist
pip install twine
twine upload dist/*
```

What am I missing here about uploading or calling the function?

Thanks for the help,

Comment: You've uploaded a broken package: the file `pycohort/__init__.py` in the package is zero length. Nothing can be imported from it. Fix the your packaging process, increase version and upload a new distribution. Use [TestPyPI](https://test.pypi.org/) to upload test packages.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. How should I fill the init file? Simply adding `import pycohort` will be enough?

Comment: You need to provide some code in your `pycohort/__init__.py`, code that implements functions for other code to import.

Comment: Then the `init` file should include `from pycohort import <function_name>` for all functions?

Comment: `pycohort/__init__.py` should include the functions itself. Where from you gonna import them? `from pycohort import` imports from `pycohort.py` or from `pycohort/__init__.py`.

Comment: I thought adding the functions only to `pycohort.py` would be enough but will add them to the `init` file as well. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You shouldn't have both `pycohort.py` and `pycohort/__init__.py`. Use one or the other, not both. `import` cannot import from both.